# Loading .dll to use in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

complete newb quesiton here, but I'm new to C# and Visual Studio 2010.

How do I load .dll's into Visual Studio 2010 so I can write C# programs using their methods?

More specifically, I'm trying to write a twitter application using [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) that will be run via command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is a .Net dll, right click on the special "References" folder for your project in Visual Studio and choose "Add Reference".  This should (eventually) open a dialog you can use to browse to the dll file.  Depending on the dll it's probably also a good idea to first add the dll to your project as a content file, so that it can eventually be deployed with the rest of your app.

Comment: Just noticed I never clicked the check.